# Run cmd command with hidden command window

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, text

i've written a simple function to output a value of a specific textbox in Access 2010 to a textfile

```
Private Sub ProcessButton_Click()
MsgBox ("Into Process Button Click")

' Assign found line to variable
Dim Outline As String
Outline = Me.TextboxFound.Value


'Save record to file
strFile_Path = OutputFile
Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
Write #1, Outline
Close #1


' Update db table

' Clear Fields
Me.TextBoxPod.Value = Null
Me.TextBoxDate.Value = Null
Me.TextboxFound.Value = Null
Me.TextBoxPod.SetFocus



End Sub
```

My problem with the above code is that : `Me.TextBoxFound.Value` in my example has the value of

```
Me.TextBoxFound.Value = 10101010102 LINE1 DATA(CRLF)
```

The above is produced from a "findstr" command.

but on the output text file, i get the following:

```
"10101010102 LINE1 DATA (CRLF)
"(CRLF)
```

Is there a way to fix this so it contains only the first line and without the ""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Write #1, Outline
```

to

```
Print #1, Outline
```

Unlike the `Print #` statement, the `Write #` statement inserts commas between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written to the file. You don't have to put explicit delimiters in the list. Write # inserts a newline character, that is, a carriage return-linefeed ( Chr( 13 ) + Chr( 10 ) ), after it has written the final character in outputlist to the file.